# Esperanto Essive Case?

Tags: adverbs

I found a wiki article stating that Esperanto has an [essive case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essive_case), but not much of an explanation. Is the essive case in Esperanto basically an -e ending at the end of a word denoting a vague statement of the time ? This is the only thing I can think of in Esperanto that might constitute an essive case:

Examples:

Vendrede - on friday

Parolante - while speaking

Semajne - weekly

If this isn't what would explain the essive case in Esperanto, what would?

And here is the source:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_grammatical_cases&oldid=899339142

Comment: Interestingly, the [Esperanto Wikipedia article about that case](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esivo) doesn't (yet?) mention its occurrence in Esperanto itself.

Comment: En la ekzemplo `Li laboras _kiel instruisto_.` temas pri `estkiel`.

Comment: The Wikipedia link refers to an old version of the article. That version contains multiple issues as others have stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the traditional grammatical analysis of Esperanto, a word ending in *-e* is an adverb. So, *vendrede* can be glossed as "friday-ly" (in German, it is quite natural, the word *freitäglich* actually exists).

Of course, anyone analysing grammar is free to reinterpret a grammatical system in their own terminology. But I am afraid that the Wikipedia article of the day cited just contains an error, and it should read "Estonian" in the place of "Esperanto".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an essive case in Finnish (and Estonian) but no such thing exists in Esperanto. The Wikipedia article listing grammatical cases is a strange concoction. Seems to me the playful Wikipedians are just trying to make the list as long as possible. For my language (Finnish), with the incredible quantity of 15 cases, they have made up ten additional ones recognized by no decent grammar. I don't know where they have found Esperanto for the essive case.